# Get rid of zeros in python

Tags: python, output

I wrote a very simple code in Python.
I need to print all the numbers between `1` and `5` (including `1` and `5`) in steps of `0.1`. The integers should be without the suffix `.0`, i.e. the output should be:

```
0
0.1
0.2
...
1
1.1
...
...
5
```

Here is my code:

```
for i in range(0,51):
    if i%10==0:
        z=int(i/10)
        print (z)
    else:
        print (i*0.1)
```

Here is my output:

```
0
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6000000000000001
0.7000000000000001
0.8
0.9
1
1.1
1.2000000000000002
1.3
1.4000000000000001
1.5
1.6
1.7000000000000002
1.8
1.9000000000000001
2
2.1
2.2
2.3000000000000003
2.4000000000000004
2.5
2.6
2.7
2.8000000000000003
2.9000000000000004
3
3.1
3.2
3.3000000000000003
3.4000000000000004
3.5
3.6
3.7
3.8000000000000003
3.9000000000000004
4
4.1000000000000005
4.2
4.3
4.4
4.5
4.6000000000000005
4.7
4.800000000000001
4.9
5
```

I don't need all this zeros `.000000001`.

Comment: Read about `floats`; then for your solution use `round()`

Comment: Or use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking advantage of Python's string formatting capabilities, you can reduce your whole loop to one line:

```
for i in range(0, 51):
    print('{:.{deci}f}'.format(i*0.1, deci=min(1, i%10)))
```

Output:

```
0
0.1
0.2
...
0.8
0.9
1
1.1
1.2
...
1.8
1.9
2
2.1
2.2
...
4.8
4.9
5
```

#### Explanation

This gives you `0` for multiples of 10 for `i` and `1` for others:

```
>>> i = 10
>>>  min(1, i%10)
0
>>> i = 8
>>> min(1, i%10)
1
```

Now, you can use this for the keyword argument `deci` to determine the number of decimals in your output:

```
>>> '{:.{deci}f}'.format(1.99, deci=1)
'2.0'
>>> '{:.{deci}f}'.format(1.99, deci=0)
'2'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print the floating point numbers rounded to 1 digit after the decimal point like so:

```
d = 1.12343214 
"{:.1f}".format(d)
>> 1.1
```

The second line formats d as a string representation of a float number rounded with 1 digit(comming from the `.1`) after the decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

You could use round or format

```
for i in range(0,51):
    if i%10==0:
        z=int(i/10)   
    else:
        z= (i*0.1)
    print '%.1f' % round(z, 1)
    print format(z, '.1f')
```

Comment: Please note this code will not work in python 3

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(0,51):
    if i%10==0:
        z=int(i/10)
        print (z)
    else:
        print ("%.1f" % (i*0.1))
```

you can use the `%.1f` notation. That will limit the number of decimals to be printed

OUTPUT

```
0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
2
2.1
2.2
2.3
2.4
2.5
2.6
2.7
2.8
2.9
3
3.1
3.2
3.3
3.4
3.5
3.6
3.7
3.8
3.9
4
4.1
4.2
4.3
4.4
4.5
4.6
4.7
4.8
4.9
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your last line into:

```
print ( "%.1f" % (i*0.1) )
```

This will format your numbers showing only one decimal position.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(0,51):
    if i%10==0:
        z= round(i/10)
        print (z)
    else:
        i = i * 0.1
        print ("%.1f" % i)
```

**Output:**

```
0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
2
2.1
2.2
2.3
2.4
2.5
2.6
2.7
2.8
2.9
3
3.1
3.2
3.3
3.4
3.5
3.6
3.7
3.8
3.9
4
4.1
4.2
4.3
4.4
4.5
4.6
4.7
4.8
4.9
5
```